# Colon error when importing JSON file into a HTML Document

Tags: html, json, google-chrome

If I write my JSON file like this:

```
{
  "content":{
    "39e3e5":{
      "date":"20070725",
      "img":"linkgoeshere",
      "title":"eclipse iss",
      "link":"vsdvsd7"
    }
  }
}
```

I get error on all the colons:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

But if I change all the colons to semicolons it works just fine.

```
{
  "content";{
    "39e3e5";{
      "date";"20070725",
      "img";"linkgoeshere",
      "title";"eclipse iss",
      "link";"vsdvsd7"
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me Why and how I can fix it?

---

Edit:
I use this tag in the HTML Head to import the JSON file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="content.json"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I use a javascript object instead:

```
var content = {
  "content":{
    "39e3e5":{
      "date":"20070725",
      "img":"linkgoeshere",
      "title":"eclipse iss",
      "link":"vsdvsd7"
    }
  }
}
```

and importing it like this:

```
<script src="content.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note: This changes it from JSON to a javascript object literal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write the name of the var without the "

Comment: Or try adding var in front of the name

Comment: You have to use quotes in JSON files. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp